# How do we refer the terms which starts with "__" in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know the terminology of the items listed when I have given the dir(sys) as an example.

Will be more clear, how we will refer these call_tracing or callstarts or copyright. Will they be called as "methods"? How can we know the usage of each attribute present in that dir list?

```
>>>import sys
>>>dir(sys)

['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', '__package__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', '_getframe', '_mercurial', 'api_version', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 'displayhook', 'dllhandle', 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_clear', 'exc_info', 'exc_traceback', 'exc_type', 'exc_value', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style', 'getcheckinterval', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getprofile', 'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'gettrace', 'getwindowsversion', 'hexversion', 'last_traceback', 'last_type', 'last_value', 'long_info', 'maxint', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'py3kwarning', 'setcheckinterval', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions', 'winver']
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/

Comment: Why don't you type `sys.call_tracing`, `sys.callstats` or anything in the list in shell to see what their type is? If it's a function. you'll get something like `<function x at 0x000000>` or `<built-in function x>`

Answer (score 1):

In general the `dir(...)` command will show you a list of all attributes present in a class. e.g. the `sys` module has attributes `'__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__name__', etc`.

If I understand your question correctly, then yes, they will be called as methods on, in your case, the sys module which contains the `call_tracing`, `callstarts`, and `copyright` methods.

For information regarding the usage of each attribute of a class, you will have to refer to the docs of that module. The sys module that you mentioned can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).

For more information on the `dir()` command you can read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).